# Converting Python GDALDataset to C++ GDALDataset

Tags: gdal, python-2.7, c++

I'm currently writing a C++ extension to python to speed up a raster data viewer which is running extremely slowly with our large datasets. I've managed to get a small speedup by writing a C++ extension, but after some investigation the slowest part in the extension is a python callback to a GDALRasterBand. Alot of this time is due to the overhead of doing a callback to python from a C-Extension,
So I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to easily convert a GDALDataset from python to a C++ GDALDataset. 
From my research into it I believe they use the same backend structure, but the python one has the additional python headers, so I don't think using the pointer reference to the python version will work.

Comment: I would advice to refactor your python code before creating an extension. 
Can you give more details why the GDALRasterBand call back is slow?

Comment: It's a call back to RasterBand.ReadAsArray, which is inherently slow anyway due to the nature of it. With one of our standard sized rasters(~30GB filesize 622 bands). The ReadAsArray in python takes ~18 seconds. and the same function as a callback from C++ takes ~23 seconds. Since the python API for gdal is a swig wrapper that adds some slowdown compared to the pure C++ version, so with the python callback adding ~7 seconds to the call, + the python version being slower than the C++ version by design, it ends up adding a lot of time onto the call. which could be avoided using the C++ RasterIO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only reading the dataset, why pass the data structure to C++? Why not pass the filename and let C++ open it shared?

That said, I *think* the C# swig wrapper has a method to get the unmanaged (i.e. C++) handle of the dataset. It is a member of the dataset object itself. See if the Python wrapper has the same thing. Although this is more dangerous than just opening the dataset in C++.

Comment: I have thought about just passing the filename in, and I've edited my script to test whether this will give any speed up(although i'm still trying to find where the filename is stored in the python code as  I didn't write it originally and it's not very well commented). My worry from some basic tests using a hardcoded filename in the C++ is that there is a slow down introduced when opening the file with gdal. Although it is quite slight with my test data(only about 30MB 3 byte raster), but I worry it could be a lot worse with some of our actual data(~30GB 622 band)

Comment: Have done it this way for now, Haven't done any profiling yet though so am not going to mark as answer until I've profiled it all to see if it's a good way to go(I would advise anyone who's not going for speed to go for the filename direction though). Will comment on speed once profiled.

Answer (score 0):

I've marked Reilly answer as the answer as that is what I am using, but thought I'd go into a bit more detail as to how to actually go about doing this.

So to actually get the filename from Python to C/C++ you need to pull in the python dataset(this doesn't have much overhead as it just takes a reference). 
then use

```
PyObject* fileString = (PyObject*)PyObject_CallMethod(gdalDataset, "GetFileList",(""),NULL);
gdalDatasetC = (GDALDataset*)GDALOpen(PyString_AsString(PyList_GetItem((PyObject*)fileString,0)), GA_ReadOnly);
```

This will pull the fileList from the python gdalDataset, take the first item. Which is the one with the main extension(atleast in my case, I haven't tested with other file extensions yet, but shouldn't be to difficult to alter it for that). Then opens it as readOnly, this barely takes any time at all so seems like the best approach to me.

On a side note: Doing this didn't speed up the application at all as it appears that RasterIO is highly unoptimized compared to Pythons ReadAsArray